# Reading an ASC file into R

Tags: r, import, raster

I'm currently trying to extract information from various "ASC" files into R in order to perform analysis on the data.

The issue is that I am unsure of how exactly to read in the files. I attempted a standard read.table functions, but all the numbers were exactly the same (-9999.00). In order to rule out the possibility of data corruption, I read in another ASC file and got the same results. The only thing I know for certain, is that the file size between them is exactly the same.

Is there anyway that I can read these files in? Any R package I can look at?

I tied this:

```
    x = read.table("Dropbox/MVZ/aet2009sep.asc")
    y = read.table("Dropbox/MVZ/aet2009oct.asc")
```

and my outputs were

```
    > head(x, n =20)
         V1        V2
    1         ncols    3486.0
    2         nrows    4477.0
    3     xllcorner -374495.8
    4     yllcorner -616153.3
    5      cellsize     270.0
    6  NODATA_value   -9999.0
    7      -9999.00   -9999.0
    8      -9999.00   -9999.0
    9      -9999.00   -9999.0
    10     -9999.00   -9999.0
    11     -9999.00   -9999.0
    12     -9999.00   -9999.0
    13     -9999.00   -9999.0
    14     -9999.00   -9999.0
    15     -9999.00   -9999.0
    16     -9999.00   -9999.0
    17     -9999.00   -9999.0
    18     -9999.00   -9999.0
    19     -9999.00   -9999.0
    20     -9999.00   -9999.0

    head(y, n =20)
         V1        V2
    1         ncols    3486.0
    2         nrows    4477.0
    3     xllcorner -374495.8
    4     yllcorner -616153.3
    5      cellsize     270.0
    6  NODATA_value   -9999.0
    7      -9999.00   -9999.0
    8      -9999.00   -9999.0
    9      -9999.00   -9999.0
    10     -9999.00   -9999.0
    11     -9999.00   -9999.0
    12     -9999.00   -9999.0
    13     -9999.00   -9999.0
    14     -9999.00   -9999.0
    15     -9999.00   -9999.0
    16     -9999.00   -9999.0
    17     -9999.00   -9999.0
    18     -9999.00   -9999.0
    19     -9999.00   -9999.0
    20     -9999.00   -9999.0
```

Comment: You cannot expect us to know what sort of errors occurred if you provide no package names or code.

Comment: You should include the contents of the raw file. I, for one, have no idea what a .asc file is or looks like.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Update: It is possible to read .asc files (aka [ESRI ASCII Raster](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) files) with the `raster` function directly from the 'raster' package. The help says:

> If x is a filename, the following additional variables are recognized:
>
> native: logical. Default is FALSE except when package rgdal is missing. If TRUE, reading and writing of ..., and Arc ASCII files is done with native (raster package) drivers, rather than via rgdal....

```
library(raster)
r = raster("C:\\...\\Dropbox/MVZ/aet2009sep.asc")
plot(r)
```

---

Edit 2 [obsolete]:

An alternative is the `raster()` function, having the package `rgdal` properly installed.

```
library(rgdal)
r = raster("C:\\...\\Dropbox/MVZ/aet2009sep.asc")
plot(r)
```

Edit 1 [obsolete]:

The package `adehabitat` is now deprecated. Currently, it provides a warning when loading it:

> It is dangerous to use it, as bugs will no longer be corrected.
>   It is now recommended to use the packages adehabitatMA, adehabitatLT, adehabitatHR, and adehabitatHS.
>   ...

Original answer [obsolete]:

Use the `import.asc` function from R package [adehabitat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitat/adehabitat.pdf) (see page 92):

```
library(adehabitat)
asc = import.asc("C:\\...\\Dropbox/MVZ/aet2009sep.asc")

#plot asc object.
library(raster)
r = raster(asc)
plot(r)
```

Comment: @Stophface, updated answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Package [`SDMTools`](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/SDMTools/read.asc.html) has the function `read.asc`, which works under R 3.2.4. However, at least in my case, using `read.table` with all default values worked out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Use Laf package, it is insanely fast.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command `x =read.csv("C:\\...\\Dropbox/MVZ//aet2009sep.asc"`, sep=";")

I found this after using the importing manually with [the import button in the Environment window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlaY5.png)