# Read ascii files in bulk in r

Tags: r, ascii

I am trying to read in ASCII files in R.

The parent directory for the files can be found [here](https://research.archives.gov/search?q=*:*&rows=20&offset=0&tabType=all&facet=true&facet.fields=oldScope,level,materialsType,fileFormat,locationIds,dateRangeFacet&highlight=true&f.parentNaId=613576&f.level=fileUnit&sort=naIdSort%20asc). I would want to read in the county-level datasets for years 1970-1985. An example file is located [here](https://catalog.archives.gov/OpaAPI/media/873790/content/arcmedia/electronic-records/rg-029/cbp-files/CBP70.DIV1-2?download=true).

The exact format for the datafiles varies, for some it is: "ASCII, fixed-length fields with one record-delimiter (line feed)"; for others: "ASCII, fixed-length fields/records with two record-delimiters (carriage return and line feed);
record length includes delimiters"

I tried to read in the data using `read.table`, `import.asc` and `raster` as discussed in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177581/reading-an-asc-file-into-r). However, they all produce an error.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do not you use `read.fwf`? or use `scan`.

Comment: I tried but these give out errors as well. Could you give a working example with one of the files on the website I linked to?

Comment: You don't have (or at least don't provide) enough information. These are fixed-width ASCII files. You need a "data dictionary" that specifies what fields are included in the file and what column positions each takes up. You can then write a `read.fwf()` statement that identifies the columns as variables.