# ASC file in one column - need to separate into 375 columns

Tags: r

I got my asc file into R. It is in one column. I need to separate into 375 columns. Having issues. I have the column widths and column names. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177581/reading-an-asc-file-into-r) helps

Comment: I am able to get the file in but its stuck in one column! The issue is parsing into 375 columns... Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Welcome to SO, still there are many open questions. How exactly should the values be split into columns? Does it depend on some properties of the data? Do we need a piece of the data to reproduce it or can we just use arbitrary numbers? If so, please provide it.

Comment: `read.fwf` **might** help you.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks. I have the column widths. Its by spaces.. for example: colWidths <- c(3,3,4,5,7,2,8)

Comment: Have you tried `read.fwf("your_file.asc", widths = colWidths)` ?  That *could* work (but without further details we're guessing, a bit).